# ASP.NET within Web Farm (multiple front end servers) with SQL Transaction

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

Is a transaction running within an asp.net web application (w/Entity Framework) ensure that updates/inserts from 2 front-end web servers make the SQL interaction safe.

We have been using this approach with one web server but we are adding a second web server and am concerned about if 2 requests come in, 1 to each server and execute similar timings can we ensure that the 1st transaction will execute safely and then the next transaction from 2nd web server will be executed (so that they do not overlap).  Within the transaction we have SQL code that inserts a row in 1 table.  So in fact we really want that SQL to insert the next greatest # based on another SQL)

Comment: You're going to be dealing with race conditions. Even on the same server/app, it's possible to insert things out of order. Better to design your system to handle this by not expecting a certain order.

Comment: It was my understanding that transactions deals with concurrency.

Comment: Sure, they can. In the database. But what happens if one web server is just running slower than the other? Perhaps Request 1 comes in first and is routed to Server A, shortly followed by Request 2 coming to Server B. However, Server A is running a little slow today, so it doesn't even start the transaction until after Server B has already started its transaction for Request 2. Now Request 2 is in the database before Request 1. Instead, what you could do is assign each request a UTC timestamp right as they come in, and make sure that both servers are synced to the same time server.

Comment: Then it wouldn't matter what order they get into the database, because as soon as the request was received you captured the time. Just record that time in the database associated with the request, and if you ever have a question about what order the requests came in, you can order on that column.

Comment: The sql job, is to get the next unique number and return it back to the request.  I just need to ensure that each gets back a unique # .  i.e. i want request #1 to get reportno #1 and request 2 to get reportno #2 as the answer.  I dont care if request 1 gets report no #2 and request 1 gets report #1 (this is ok)..i just have to ensure that each/both requests don't get reportno #1

Comment: If you need a unique value, a [Guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=netframework-4.8) would probably be better.

Comment: It has to be numeric incrementing by 1 for end user report number field